# Precision of chrono::system_clock::now in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++-chrono

I am seeing a weird behavior when calling `chrono::system_clock::now()` on VS2015. If you call `chrono::system_clock::now()` in a loop the time_points generated seem to have a precision of 1 millisec. Here is the code:

```
using cl = chrono::system_clock;
set<cl::time_point> s;
for( int i=0; i <1000'000;++i) {
    s.emplace(cl::now());
}
for(const auto& x : s) {
    cout << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(x.time_since_epoch()).count() << endl;
}
cout << "size of set " << s.size() << endl;
```

Here is the tail of the output time stamps (in nanosec):

```
1,501,268,149,325,000,700
1,501,268,149,326,000,700
1,501,268,149,327,000,700
1,501,268,149,328,000,700
1,501,268,149,329,000,700
1,501,268,149,330,000,700
1,501,268,149,331,000,700
1,501,268,149,332,000,700
1,501,268,149,333,000,700
1,501,268,149,334,000,700
1,501,268,149,335,000,700
1,501,268,149,336,000,700
1,501,268,149,337,000,700
1,501,268,149,338,000,700
1,501,268,149,339,000,700
1,501,268,149,340,000,700
1,501,268,149,341,000,700
1,501,268,149,342,000,700
1,501,268,149,343,000,700
1,501,268,149,344,000,700
size of set 89
```

As can be seen from the time stamps it seems like the system_clock is generating times with 1 millisec precision. Although windows system_clock is supposed to have a precision of 100 nanosec. Note that for a million messages it only produced 89 distinct time stamps.

If we run the same code with clang we do not see this problem and the precision in that case is 1 microsec. Also using steady_clock on VS2015 the precision is 1  nanosec.

Does any one know why system_clock behaves this way on VS2015 ?

Comment: When I run your code, compiled with VS 2015, I see steps of 100 ns.  I suspect you're inadvertently compiling and/or linking against an older version of the VS's standard library.  MSDN says changes were made to the clocks in VS 2015 to be more compliant with the standard.

Comment: I am compiling against VS 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Comment: That's the exact version I'm using, but I can't reproduce your results.  Are you sure that you're getting the corresponding version of the standard library and not somehow picking up an older one?

Comment: Yes I am positive it is the correct version, a few other folks have confirmed this. Some of them have seen a difference of 1,000,000,100 nano i.e., 1 milliseconds and 100 nano. It is easy to miss the 1 milliseconds part.

Comment: Will like to add that it is running on WIn2k8.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation by Microsoft is like this:

```
namespace std
{
    namespace chrono
    {
        struct system_clock
        {
            static time_point now() __NOEXCEPT
            {
                return (time_point(duration(_Xtime_get_ticks())));
            }
```

*_Xtime_get_ticks()* uses *GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()*.  This function's precision is 1 millisecond.

Comment: but 'typedef ratio_multiply<ratio<_XTIME_NSECS_PER_TICK, 1>, nano> period;' where _XTIME_NSECS_PER_TICK==100. that means you may file a bug report to MSDN.

Comment: [Citation needed] that `_Xtime_get_ticks()` uses `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`